# Which scenes from The Force Awakens trailers didn't make it into the film?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, deleted-scenes, trailer

There often are scenes and/or dialog shown in trailers for a film which don't make the final cut. Were there any for *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*?

Which trailer scenes didn't make it into the final cut?

*(I'm including TV Spots and International trailers)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This article](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/star-wars-bait-and-switch-what-was-in-force-171019205.html) identifies several; and [this one](http://whatculture.com/film/star-wars-the-force-awakens-10-moments-from-the-trailers-not-in-the-movie.php/2) even more

- The infamous lighting of <strike>Christmas Tree</strike> Kylo Ren's crossguard lightsaber in the forest

  [image]
- Maz offering *someone* Luke's lightsaber (who isn't Finn - who she ends up giving the Hot Potato in the film). According to the [EW](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/22/star-wars-force-awakens-jj-abrams-deleted-scenes) J.J. Abrams interview, it's Leia.

  [image]
- Luke's "The Force is strong in my Family. So we will all burn down the Galaxy to Ashes as we battle one another" Force monologue

Some of the more minor ones:

- Rey hot-rodding her speeder. In the film she is never shown to.
- Panning wide shot of Jakku dunes.
- BB-8 peeking around the Falcon
- “Who are you?” “I’m no one” Maz/Rey dialog, voiced over Rey cleaning up Star Destroyer junk on Jakku
- “I was raised to do one thing, but I’ve got nothing to fight for.” with helmetless Finn
- X-Wings flying over the lake surface

  [image]

---

They quoted EW interview with J.J. Abrams confirming the missing shots:

> There’s a shot where Kylo Ren turns on his lightsaber, which was also not in the movie,” director J.J. Abrams acknowledges. “There were a bunch of things we ended up not using.”

Answer (score 2):

Per the super-thorough rundown on [io9](http://io9.gizmodo.com/all-the-stuff-from-the-force-awakens-trailers-that-wasn-1748720944), there are scenes missing:

- Rey driving off in her speeder. (Missed by io9)
- Kylo Ren activating his lightsaber.
- Maz handing Anakin/Luke's lightsaber to Leia ([Source](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-the-force-awkens-deleted-scenes/3/)).

The trailers have longer cuts of some scenes that are in the film:

- Rey leaving the Star Destroyer wreckage.
- Rey looking into the distance while cleaning her loot ([Source](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-the-force-awkens-deleted-scenes/4/)).
- Finn waking up after the crash.
- Kylo Ren and the Knights of Ren in the rain, from Rey's vision.

Dialogue in the trailers, not in the film:

- Maz asking Rey, "Who are you?" and her response of, "No one."
- Luke Skywalker's "The Force is strong in my family" speech.
- Finn - "I was raised to do one thing, and I’ve got nothing to fight for."
- Kylo Ren - "Nothing will stand in our way. I’ll show them the Dark Side."
- Maz Kanata - "Hope is not lost today. It is found."

Answer (score 0):

Not a trailer, technically, but part of the promotional campaign, tied in with O2:

If you've seen *The Force Awakens*, you know that there was never an opportunity for R2-D2 and C-3PO to meet BB-8 in a desert environment, because

> R2-D2 is asleep for almost the entire film, and C-3PO never leaves the Resistance base.