# Where in the movie was this scene with R2-D2 and BB-8 supposed take place?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, droids

One of the Promos for *The Force Awakens* shows [R2-D2 and C-3PO meeting BB-8 in a desert](http://youtu.be/A-s5dcVAD-A), probably Jakku.

Where in the movie was this supposed to go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which scenes from The Force Awakens trailers didn't make it into the film?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113874/which-scenes-from-the-force-awakens-trailers-didnt-make-it-into-the-film)

Comment: Answered here:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113882/44025

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't.

That scene was invented entirely for that promotional clip, and has nothing at all to do with the plot of the movie.

Note that the clip is *not* a *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* commercial, as it has sometimes been incorrectly labelled on YouTube. It's a commercial for a UK mobile service provider, [O2](http://www.o2.co.uk/) as you can see from the quote and clip below.

> UK telecommunications services provider O2 has begun airing a new commercial which features our old trusty droid friends R2-D2 and C3PO, who are wandering the desert planet of Jakku in hopes of finding help. And help they find, in the form of BB-8, the new droid from Star Wars: The Force Awakens. The footage does not appear to be from the movie itself <sup>[src](http://www.slashfilm.com/r2-d2-and-c-3po-meet-bb-8-o2-commercial/)</sup>

Comment: There is also a similar TV advertisement for a new house design from a Housing Developer here in Japan which has absolutely nothing to do with Star Wars at all...

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder do you have a link?